# "I was stupid to followed her advice"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> 1: *I was stupid to followed her advice*
> 2: *I was stupid that I followed her advice*
> 3: *I was stupid to have followed her advice*
> 4: *I was stupid that I had followed her advice*

Do these 4 sentences mean the same?

Comment: You haven't given the shortest acceptable version: *I was stupid to follow her advice*. But although it's more words, I much prefer ***It was stupid of me** to follow her advice*. See [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+stupid+to%2CIt+was+stupid+of+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20stupid%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20was%20stupid%20of%20me%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica ok are the examples with the that-clause correct grammatically and semantically? An also all of them 4 sentences mean the same?

Comment: (1) is ungrammatical (as FF says, it should be _to follow_). (2) and (4) are not very idiomatic.

Comment: I can just about go along with ***It** was stupid **that** I followed her advice*, but I don't like it much. And I can't accept ***any*** versions that start with the personal pronoun ***I*** and also include the relativiser ***that***. Choosing between OP's 4 alternatives, none of which are *really* idiomatic, looks like an Off Topic "primarily opinion-based" question to me.

Comment: Give 2 and 4 some tweaks and they can work: _I was **so** stupid that I followed her advice._ _I was stupid **in** that I followed her advice._

Comment: @EddieKal i know im not a native speaker but i dont understand why you put 'in' in your example. It doesn't make much sense to me Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Check out the definition of ["in that"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20that)

Comment: @EddieKal wow thanks!

Comment: Aren't all those sentences badly worded?

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica But how to explain [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+stupid+to%2Cwas+stupid+of+me+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20stupid%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20stupid%20of%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an animate (or rational) subject, *stupid* takes a "to" infinitive clause:

> I was stupid to follow/to have followed her advice

With an impersonal subject ("it"), *stupid* can take either a "to" infinitive clause, or a "that" clause:

> 1. It was stupid to follow her advice

> 2. It was stupid that I followed her advice.

If you want to specify the subject, you can use *for* with a "to" infinitive:

> 3. It was stupid for me to follow her advice.

but you can also specify the person who was stupid with "of" in either case:

> 4. It was stupid of me to follow her advice.

> 5. It was stupid of me that I followed her advice.

(My 3 and 4 have nearly the same meaning, but different structures: in 3, *for me to follow her advice* is the complement clause, with *me* as its subject; in 4, the complement is *to follow her advice* without a subject, and *of me* is an adjunct of "stupid".)

The facts that I have given about what the word takes in the different uses are arbitrary facts that happen to be how the word behaves in current English: there is no rule or logic that will tell you them.

On the question of past infinitive/past perfect: these are used when the speaker wishes to locate something in time relative to some later viewpoint. They are nearly always optional, and are often not used when the temporal relationships are clear without them. In your 3 and 4, the speaker is choosing to focus the time at some point later than their following the advice: it is presumably clear to their hearers when this time was that they are "looking back" from. If they use your 1 and 2, they are not placing a viewpoint at any particular time.